# Compare two hashmaps in javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to find a solution to compare two hashmaps in javascript but I have a difficulty.

This is my situation, I have a hashmap composed of a `key + value` in form of an array.

Example : `125 : [1 , 2 , 3]`

And then I take this data and I compare it with another hashmap with this kind.

Example :

```
123 : [[1 , 1 , 1][2 , 8.7 , 10]]
124 : [[0 , 0, 5.4][3 , 4 , 5][7, 9.1 , 6]
125 : [[1 , 2 , 3][0.4 , 4 , 8]]
```

The second hashmap is similar to the first , but its value could contain an array of N arrays. The goal : To parse the second hashmap with my first hashmap and firstly find if the keys are similar, then if once it finds the value of the first in an array of the second it must return "OK"

For example in this case : it will return `"OK"` because we can notice that the `key 125` and her `value` in the first hashmap are included in `125 : [[1 , 2 , 3][0.4 , 4 , 8]]`

I should not only test on the values ​​but also on the keys

Here is another example :

Notice that the first hashmap always have 1 data (key+value) 1 key + 1 array of 1 dimension

1st hashmap : `var hashmap1 = { 124 : [ 1,1,1] }`

2nd hashmap :

```
    var hashmap2 = { 
        123 : [0,0,0],
        124 : [[ 0,1,1][0,0,1][1,1,1]]
        125 : [9 , 8 , 7]
    }
```

Result : "OK" , because `124 : [1,1,1]` is found in `124 :` [[ 0,1,1][0,0,1]`[1,1,1]`] .

Comment: So, you want to see if the key(s) from the first hashmap are actually in the second one and then check to see if their keys are the same?

Comment: exactly, like this example : 125 : [1 , 2 , 3] of the first hashmap is included in 125 : [[1 , 2 , 3][0.4 , 4 , 8]] .. Once he found the key, he check if its values are the same and return "OK" if it does or "NO" if it doesn't

Comment: I think this is very difficult to understand, as I found myself reading and re-reading the question numerous times, and still dont have a perfectly clear understanding of the requirements. Perhaps you can make things much clearer by providing 5 - 6 test cases with the expected results.

Comment: Here is the edited version, it seems clear now?

Answer (score 2):

```
const compareHashMap = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1), keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
  let match = true;
  if(keys1.length !== keys2.length) return false;
  for(const key of keys1) { 
      if(obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
          match = false; 
            break; 
      }
  }
  return match;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to compare the arrays is to stringify them and see if the sample one exists in the other string

```js
let sample = {
  '124': [9,9,9], // expect no match .. key exists but array differs
  '125': [1, 2, 3], //expect match
  '555':[8,8] // expect no match ... key doesn't exist
}

let data = {
  '123': [ [1, 1, 1],[2, 8.7, 10]],
  '124': [[0, 0, 5.4],[3, 4, 5],[7, 9.1, 6]],
  '125': [[1, 2, 3],[0.4, 4, 8]]
}

let res = Object.keys(sample).map(key => {
   let msg = 'OK';
   if(!data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      msg= 'No Match';
   }else{
      let arrayMatch = JSON.stringify(data[key]).indexOf(JSON.stringify(sample[key])) >-1;
      msg = !arrayMatch ? 'No Match' : msg;
   }
   return key + ' : ' +  msg;
});

console.log(res.join('\n'))
```

Comment: I think this is it, i'll try it later. Now i'm on my phone ... But my first hashmap only include 1 key and 1 value .. it won't be a problem?

Comment: and i won't a final result , not a message for each one

Comment: Be more specific about expected results

Comment: Like charlietl did , I compare the key and value of the first hashmap (it only have one key and one value) with the second hashmap that contains a lot of keys and values. the goal is to search if the key + value of the first is founded in the second hashmap and then return message OK if true or "NO" if it hasn't be find

Comment: And that's what the code I have does... modify it to return something different if you need

Comment: If you know what the value is of the key in the sample...can simplify this  a bit

Comment: I still couldn't implement your method in my case. In let sample i have only one key and value (not 3 like in your example) and I return only one message.